# Converting decimal to different bases

Tags: ios, objective-c, arbitrary-precision

I'm writing a program to compute the conversion of number system. My goal is to let the program compute very large number at a short time (<0.1s) and I made a NSString category to let me compute very large number (+ - * / %), a function to convert any base number to decimal, I think it's fast enough.

The problem is here: convert decimal to different bases. It is never fast enough, my algorithm even take me >10s to convert from decimal to binary or memory error.

```
- (NSString *)decimalToBase:(int)baseOfNewNumber
{
    NSString *quotient, *remainder, *result;

    result = @"";
    quotient = number;

    if (number != 0 && baseOfNewNumber != 10) {

        for (int count = 0; [quotient compare:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", baseOfNewNumber] options:NSNumericSearch] == (NSOrderedDescending|NSOrderedSame); count++) {
            remainder = [quotient stringByModuloByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", baseOfNewNumber]];
            quotient = [quotient stringByDividedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", baseOfNewNumber]];
            result = [remainder stringByAppendingString:result];
        }
        result = [[quotient stringByModuloByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", baseOfNewNumber]] stringByAppendingString:result];
        return result;
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Lastly, this website converting the very very large number very fast, I saw its source code, it's likely simply using the usual method like me!
http://www.convertworld.com/en/numerals/

Comment: Why not convert to a NSDecimalNumber and then do your math.   There's a great chance that you're trying to do a NSNumericSearch on a number like 1.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333  EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you mean the `compare: options:` method will cause error first but not  NSDecimalNumber reach its upper limit first?

Comment: I'm worried that you're taking in a floating point number and ending up with an infinite string.   But you shouldn't be... this algorithm would appear to only work on integers. 

Above and beyond that, I worry about casting your intermediate values into strings.  It's just odd.  What I meant was that NSDecimalNumber is probably going to use a few bytes to accurately represent 4/3, but a string would be infinitely large depending on if your stringByDividedByString method allows floating point values.  Which it shouldn't, for this algorithm.

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't mention I'm only working for the integers at the moment, converting floats is about a different algorithm (I think), but I will working on converting float number later also (after I fixed this..) And again, thanks for your reply.